# MomentJS issue with timezone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, momentjs

I am using moment JS to handle my dates.

Setup :

One DateTime input element
   One Time Input Element

Lets says I have these values :

```
DateTime = "05/30/2016" and StartTime = "10:00";
```

I am doing this to convert from local time to UTC time :

```
utcTime = moment(DateStart+ " " + StartTime).toDate().toISOString(),
```

but when print the utcTime value I am getting,  "2016-05-30T10:00:00+01:00"
That +01:00 , is messing up my time when passing it back to the server (hosted in the same machine as the client, development machine)  when I get the data back in the server it reports back as 9H instead of 10H , due to the +1 offset. My time zone is set to 0 (LISBON timezone), so the offset should be 0.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the +01:00 from the string doing a simple regular expression before you send it back to the server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using moment, there is generally no need to ever call `.toDate()` unless you are dealing with a third party API. In your situation though, I believe all you want is to convert your date from local to UTC. You are almost there, but you have a couple of things you need to clean up. Your resultant code should be:

```
var date ="05/30/2016"; 
var time ="10:00";  
moment(date+ " " + time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').utc().format()
"2016-05-30T15:00:00Z"
```

A few things to note about this code:

My current time zone is UTC-5 right now. As you can see, the time has changed from 10:00 to 15:00 UTC -  this conversion is correct.

I have specified a format for the input string. This is very important. Right now you are receiving a warning that says:

> Moment construction falls back to JS Date

This is an important warning. Without the format, your code will behave differently in different browsers, and when running in different countries. More info here: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/

Finally, you can see that I parse with the `moment()` constructor, and then call `.utc()`. When you parse with the `moment()` constructor, you are saying 'interpret this data as the user's local time zone`. When you call `.utc()`  you are saying 'now display this same point in time as UTC'.

I need to also note, Lisbon is UTC +1 right now due to daylight saving time. The value you are seeing right now is correct. It is 9:00 UTC.

Comment: And right now I am feeling and utter idiot due to the daylight savings which I forgot, so lets see if I got this correct.

User enters values in inputs :
 I use moment "moment(date+ " " + time, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm').utc().format()" to get the date back in UTC and send it to server.

Once I receive the date from the server, I do moment().utc(datevalue).format()  correct ? Since the utc means I am partsing a utc value right?

Eitherway you have been a major help! thank you!

Comment: This depends on your date format. Is it in ISO8601 extended with offset? (2016-01-01T00:00:00.00+01:00)? If so, then you can just use the moment constructor, and it will automatically convert from the provided offset to user's local time. If you have no offset, then you would use moment.utc(date, format).local() to change back to local.

Comment: I wrote this really long blog post about how moment handles offsets, and all of it's constructor functions: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Comment: Also, the guides might help: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

Comment: Your post was extremely helpful, seems like everything is working fine right now. Thanks alot!